# ZK Absolute Layout issue With ZUL page?

Tags: layout, zk

I am trying to use the absolute layout in my webpage and added that absolute layout inside borderlayout and now absolute layout's contain a absolute children and it contain difrent component something like this..

```
<zk xmlns:x="xhtml" xmlns:zk="zk">
        <borderlayout width="100%" height="100%"
                apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
                viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.web.viewmodel.MyEditViewModel')">
        <north border="none">
        //ToolBar will come here
        </north>
        <center border="none" sclass="sub-tab-panel">
                    <vlayout vflex="1" hflex="1" sclass="vertical-scroll"
                          draggable="sizer">
        <separator />
                        <groupbox mold="3d">
        <x:table cellpadding="3" width="500px" height="350px">

        <absolutelayout id="mainLayout" droppable="abschild">
        <absolutechildren>
        <label draggable="abschild" value="Type" sclass="field-label" />

        <label draggable="abschild" value="@bind(vm.folderType)" />
        </absolutechildren>
        <absolutechildren>
        <label draggable="abschild" value="Select" sclass="field-label" />
        <combobox draggable="abschild" model="@load(vm.statusCodeOptions)" selectedItem="@bind(vm.statusCode)"/>
        </absolutechildren>
        </x:table>
        </groupbox>
     </vlayout>

        <center>
    </borderlayout>
</zk>
```

Now My issue is that after using AbsoluteLayout nothing is displaying in the page anyone know what is the issue?

FIddle example image..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess the x:table means xhtml table, what you need is adding tr and td (with specified height):

i.e.,

```
<x:table cellpadding="3" width="500px" height="350px">
    <x:tr><x:td style="height: 350px;">
        <absolutelayout ...
    </x:td></x:tr>
</x:table>
```

you also need to specify x and y of one absolutechidren:

```
<absolutechildren x="10" y="100">
```

see [sample at zkfiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2jn29a4/5-Absolutelayout-in-xhtml-table)

test result

[image: absolutelayout test]

Comment: Hi ben i just run your example in fiddle there also no any component is displayed

Comment: See images added by me same thing happeing in IE(9.0.8112) as well as Firefox19.0 not able to see any component

Comment: it seems caused by the sizing rule of IE/Firefox, specify a height to td than it is fixed, the sample is updated.

Comment: Hi Ben can we restrict draggable and droppable attribute  so that when we click on any menu item then absolutelayout will draggable and droppable otherwise it worked normally without draggable and droppable feature?

Comment: @subodh, actually draggable/droppable are matched via string, an item with 'draggable="strOne"' will work with some other items with 'droppable="strOne"', just handle the draggable/droppable attribute as need.